# how to add another screen on navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using a tab bottom navigator in my project. I want to show a new page in a tab of the tab bottom navigator but I want the tab navigator to appear again at the bottom. I don't want to add the button of the new page I want to show below. How do I manage this situation.I created the new scene as another js file and added it to the app js. I mean. I have a button to redirect to a new page in the Home tab, but how do I navigate
 my navigator codes in app.js:

```
import LoadingScreen from './screens/LoadingScreen'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen'
import ProfileScreen from './screens/profileScreen'
import NotificationScreen from './screens/notificationScreen'
import PostScreen from './screens/postScreen'
import soruOnaylaScreen from './screens/soruOnaylaScreen'

const AppContainer = createStackNavigator(
  {
    default: createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        soruOnayla: {
          screen: soruOnaylaScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
              <Ionicons name="ios-chatboxes" size={24} color={tintColor} />
          }
        },
        Home: {
          screen: HomeScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
              <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={24} color={tintColor} />
          }
        },

        Post: {
          screen: PostScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
              <Ionicons
                name="ios-add-circle"
                size={36}
                color='#E9446A'
                style={{
                  shadowColor: "#E9446A",
                  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
                  shadowRadius: 10,
                  shadowOpacity: 0.3
                }}
              />
          }
        }
        , Notification: {
          screen: NotificationScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
              <Ionicons name="ios-notifications" size={24} color={tintColor} />
          }
        },
        Profile: {
          screen: ProfileScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
              <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={24} color={tintColor} />
          }
        }
      },
      {

        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: "#161f3d",
          inactiveTintColor: "#b8bbc4",

        }
      }
    ),
    postModal: {
      screen: PostScreen
    } 
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
)


const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Register: RegisterScreen

})  


export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    { 
      Loading: LoadingScreen,
      App: AppContainer,
      Auth: AuthStack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Loading"
    }
  )
)
```